# Audio Bug on 1 of 2 Client iPhones (Xcode + Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, audio

So I've just finished building a clients app and all was good.  The app worked seamlessly on both mine and the clients phone.  However the clients partner tried it on an iPhone 5s and audio did not play.  I then tried running the app on an alternative iPhone 5s as oppose to the client's partners (6s) and it works fine.

I think the problem is their phone however maybe I'm wrong - although audio in safari works fine for them.

I am using a standard web view but don't know why it's just their phone.  Are there any reasons maybe a specific device wouldn't allow sound in the app?

Thanks.

Comment: check this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31152/iphone-wont-play-sound-in-some-apps and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3008964?start=30